# Prevent Unauthenticated Access to Uploaded Document URLs - MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies

My application(MVC3) allows users to upload their documents on a form. Once uploaded, access to these documents is available to anonymous users by visiting the link containing the document ID and request ID in the URL.

Ex: 
`https://myapplication.com/Documents/DownloadDocument/DwldDocumentMethod?DocumentId=fg2ac782-a15a-445a-b0e9-b11344878f28&RequestId=gh998c01-1d27-40b6-9e55-127084ca164b`

Need to secure uploaded document URLs from unauthorized access by requiring  authenticated user's session cookie.

In MVC3, what are all the possible ways to implement session cookie. I really appreciate, if any other possible ways.

Comment: I think the download of files should be handled only through the Controller actions, and not by the file URL.. So if your Action is secured then your document is also secured. Please refer to link - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/65794e/uploading-and-downloading-in-mvc/ to implement upload/ download in proper way

Answer (score 3):

To secure the download of a file you need to control it by an Action.
So you have to create a controller passing the name of the file and through that you can send back the Binary data.

for example:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "RegisteredUser,Admin")]
public Action DownloadFile(string fileName){
    //Read the file:
    string mimeType = "";
    byte[] myFile = ReadMyFile(fileName, out mimeType);

    return File(myFile,mimeType,fileName);
}
```